# Unable to hide Chromedriver console with CREATE_NO_WINDOW

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, subprocess

1. Python 3.11
2. ChromeDriver 107.0.5304.62
3. Chrome 107.0.5304.107
4. Selenium 4.6.0

Chromedriver console always shows when I try to build exe with pyinstaller.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
    from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.binary_location = r'D:\Test\bin\chrome.exe'
    
    chrome_service = ChromeService(r'D:\Test\bin\chromedriver.exe')
    chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service, options=chrome_options)
    driver.get('http://google.com')
```

I have tried to build exe with pyinstaller in different ways:

```
pyinstaller Test.py
pyinstaller Test.pyw
pyinstaller Test.py  --windowed      or  --noconsole
pyinstaller Test.pyw --windowed      or  --noconsole
```

I also tried to change in venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py at line 67

```
self.creation_flags = 0
```

to

```
self.creation_flags = 1
```

I also tried different chrome/chromedriver combinations

Comment: Are there selenium logs appearing on the console window? Please show the text that appears on that console window.

Comment: http://ibb.co/bPbBJ5Q. You can see console log here. It work correctly with 4.5.0. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work with selenium 4.6.0 version. It work with selenium 4.5.0

Answer (score 4):

It appears that somewhere along the line (not sure which release), "creationflags" changed to "creation_flags".

Try changing your code from:

chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

to

chrome_service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

Try to figure out what happend, I just found this [commit](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/ba04acdf9ea3e53c483cc38a1ae796496e5da9c1) change **Service** varaible from `creationflags` to `creation_flags`.

For the people who want to hide the console window for **ChromDriver**. You have to use `selenium` with version above 4.0.0.

If before 4.5.0:

```
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

Or after 4.6.0

```
chrome_service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```